# Android: I can´t get data from my database in a second activity using SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm currently working an application on Android Studio and I have a little problem, hope you can help me. This application is made using Model-View-Presenter and in the Login activity (the main activity). I call a REST service to get data and save it in the data base, in the interactor class I have this mehtod to save the data of the JSON object in the database

```
private long insertLoginData() throws JSONException {
    HelperDB dbObj = new HelperDB(_ctx);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String firstName = "";
    String lastName = "";

    values.put(userTableFields[1], _objJson.getString(userTableFields[1]));
    if (_objJson.has("fullName")){
        JSONObject objFullName = _objJson.getJSONObject("fullName");
        firstName = (objFullName.has(userTableFields[2]) ? objFullName.getString(userTableFields[2]) : "");
        lastName = (objFullName.has(userTableFields[3]) ? objFullName.getString(userTableFields[3]) : "");
    }
    values.put(userTableFields[2], firstName);
    values.put(userTableFields[3], lastName);
    values.put(userTableFields[4], (_objJson.has(userTableFields[4]) ? _objJson.getString(userTableFields[4]) : ""));
    values.put(userTableFields[5], true);
    values.put(userTableFields[6], _userName);
    values.put(userTableFields[7], _Password);

    long localId = dbObj.insertStatement(0, values);
    dbObj.closeDB();
    return localId;
}
```

_ctx is a local variable of Context in the Presenter, it comes from Main Activity. And userTableFields Array contains the name of fields of my table users and it comes from the strings resource.

I know, this is a manual way to do it, I could use POJO to cast in classes the model of the JSON data, but this is no the problem. I use the debug console to check localId variable is returning a value different to -1, so record is inserting ok in the database.

After validate the user and insert the user records (user informations and its notifications) to data base I open a new Activity (the second activity) and then I call a method in the Presenter to get the user data and trying to show it in this new activity.

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements HomeView{
private HomePresenter presenter;
private ListView lvNotifications;
private TextView tvWelcome;
private ProgressBar pbHome;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    presenter = new HomePresenterImpl(this);
    lvNotifications = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvNotifications);
    tvWelcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvWelcome);
    pbHome = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pbHome);
    setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.titleHome));

    presenter.getNotificationsDataPresenter(getApplicationContext());

    lvNotifications.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //presenter.getSelectedItem(position, _linkResource);
        }
    });
}

    @Override
public void setDataSourceListView(String[] itemArray, String[] linkResource) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemArray);
    lvNotifications.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

The problem is here. In the Presenter of the second activity I call a method in the database to get the notifications of users, even, if I change the sentence directly to "SELECT * FROM users" it always comes empty, I searched lot of topics about it but do not get solution.

This is the method to get data of users and does not work although inserts are happening satisfactorily in the first activity.

```
private void getNotificationsData(String query){
    HelperDB dbObj = new HelperDB(_ctx);

    Cursor cursor = dbObj.getQueryStatement(query, null);

    itemArray = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    linkResource = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int i = 0;

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        try{
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                itemArray[i] = cursor.getString(0);
                linkResource[i] = cursor.getString(1);
                i++;
            }
        }
        finally {
            cursor.close();
            dbObj.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking it could be an issue about the Context, because en the first Activity I execute other functions in the data base and there are no problems, but in the second activity data of any kind is returned, the Cursor does not break or throw error, its variable mCount always is -1 and size is 0.

The following is the SQLiteOpenHelper that I'm using to connect the database.

```
public class HelperDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static final String DBName = "MyDb";
private static String createUserTableStatement = "";
private static String createNotificationsTableStatement = "";

String[] tableNames, userTableFields, notificationsTableFields;

public HelperDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DBName, null, 1);

    tableNames = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tableNames);
    userTableFields = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.userTableFields);
    notificationsTableFields = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.notificationsTableFields);

    createUserTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE " + tableNames[0] + " (" + userTableFields[0] + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + userTableFields[1] + " TEXT, " + userTableFields[2] + " TEXT, " + userTableFields[3]
            + " TEXT, " + userTableFields[4] + " TEXT, " + userTableFields[5] + " BOOLEAN, " + userTableFields[6] + " TEXT, "
            + userTableFields[7] + " TEXT)";

    createNotificationsTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE " + tableNames[1] + " (" + notificationsTableFields[0]
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + notificationsTableFields[1] + " TEXT, "
            + notificationsTableFields[2] + " TEXT, " + notificationsTableFields[3]
            + " TEXT, " + notificationsTableFields[4] + " TEXT, " + notificationsTableFields[5] + " TEXT)";
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(createUserTableStatement);

    db.execSQL(createNotificationsTableStatement);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tableNames.length; i++)
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableNames[i]);

    onCreate(db);
}

public void closeDB() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    if (db != null && db.isOpen())
        db.close();
}

public long insertStatement(int tableIndex, ContentValues values){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long userId;
    try{
        db.beginTransaction();
        userId = db.insert(tableNames[tableIndex], null, values);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
    finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();
    }
    return userId;
}

public Cursor getQueryStatement(String queryStatement, String[] fieldsArray){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryStatement, fieldsArray);

    return cursor;
}
```

}

The question is what I'm doing wrong when I want to get data records in a second activity that previously in a prevoius activity were inserted?

Note: I always send getApplicationContext as parameter to the Presenter because methods in the SqliteOpenHelper needs the context in the construtor.

Comment: Where calling `getNotificationsData` ?

Comment: In the presenter layer (other class), presenter.getNotificationsDataPresenter(getApplicationContext()); --> I catch the context and assign it to a local variable --> in a variable I set the "SELECT * FROM users" --> getNotificationsData(String query)

Answer (score 0):

You should make POJO class and implement Parcelable like below code just modify your params

```
public class User implements Parcelable {
private Integer id;
private String userName;
private Integer age;


public User() {
}

protected User(Parcel in) {
    userName = in.readString();
    age = in.readInt();
}

public static final Creator<User> CREATOR = new Creator<User>() {
    @Override
    public User createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new User(in);
    }

    @Override
    public User[] newArray(int size) {
        return new User[size];
    }
};

public Integer getId() {

    return id;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(userName);
    parcel.writeInt(age);
}
```

Then using intent put your model into intent and getIntent in another activity where you want like:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,//your activity name);
            intent.putExtra("yourModekey",userModel);
    startActivities(intent);
```

in other activity get like

```
getIntent().getParcelableExtra("yourModelkey");
```

Comment: In the second activity getQueryStatement(String queryStatement, String[] fieldsArray) does not work like if: The records in the first activity were not really inserted, in the first activity data was saved in a different context and using the Context of second activity is not the same, the way to get data in second activity is wrong